# i'm not being able to print a data frame made from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas

this is the code

```
import pandas as pd
emp_details={'employee':{"dave":{"id":"001","salary":"192373","designation":"team lead"},"john":{"id":"002","salary":"1000","designation":"associate"}}}
df=pd.dataframe(emp_details['employee'])
print(df)
```

for some reason it is giving me a syntax error even after i tried making it a exact replica of the tutorial i'm looking at.

the interpreter is not giving me any error its only when i run it that it gives me a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas is a case sensitive so while using we should be careful 
here

```
df=pd.DataFrame(emp_details['employee'])
```

now print it

```
print(df)
```

here you made mistake in writing

```
pd.dataFrame()
```